# How to submit multiple jobs in Abaqus using python script

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm trying to figure out how to submit multiple Abaqus jobs within the same cae file using a python script from the cmd line.

I've tried multiple variations of the following script with no luck

```
import os

File=openMdb(pathname="ATF-1-157C_157D_158A_Oct2015")
myJob1 = mdb.Job(name='A01_AB', model=A01_As-Built, description=jobDescription)
myJob1.submit()
```

I keep getting errors about the mdb not being recognized.

I've also tried putting

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
```

at the first of the file and get errors about the abaqus kernel

Thanks

Comment: post the actual error messages and show how you run the script

Comment: the `model=` and `description=` keyword arguments take strings.

Comment: That helped. I put an ' around A01_As-Built and jobDescription and it ran. I also deleted the File= step......Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
mdb.Job(name='Job-1', model='Model-1', description='', type=ANALYSIS, 
atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90, 
memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True, 
explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, echoPrint=OFF, 
modelPrint=OFF, contactPrint=OFF, historyPrint=OFF, userSubroutine='', 
scratch='', resultsFormat=ODB, parallelizationMethodExplicit=DOMAIN, 
numDomains=1, activateLoadBalancing=False, multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, 
numCpus=1)
```

keyword "model" filled by a string . i suggest you copy the abaqus replay file .rpy to help you write your own script, it do really helpful.